# Django templates: model.image.url gets relative url, how to get full domain url?

Tags: python, django

I'm new to Django and I've been trying to get my images to show on a site I'm building.

On my templates I use `<img src="{{ model.image.url }}" />` and I get the `MEDIA_URL` + `IMAGE_PATH`.

Something like this: `upload/gallery/zips/thumbnails/zips.png`. `upload/` is my `MEDIA_URL`.

How can I get my url to look something like: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload/gallery/zips/thumbnails/zips.png` without having to append it like this:
`<img src="http://127.0.0.1:8000/{{ gallery.thumbnail.url }}" />`?

So sorry if this is the stupidest question ever asked on SO.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: Mmm to access the images from any part of my website, supposed I have a url like this: `/gallery/image/show/23/`. Then the relative url wouldn't work. @marcusshep

Comment: You almost never want to hard code a domain. Say you wanted to deploy this app to a production server. You then would have to change every `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` to the production servers IP address. it would be better to find another solution to your problem.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to solve with my question here. There must be something else that I can do to achieve this. :-)

Comment: Oh I see, sorry for misinterpreting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can prepend your media url using the request object:

```
<img src="{{ request.get_host }}{{ model.image.url }}" />
```

*Note - you'll want to make sure you have `request` in your template context processors:

```
'django.template.context_processors.request'
```

Comment: Thank you but it actually gives me: `<img src="127.0.0.1:8000upload/gallery/zips/thumbnails/zips.png" />` and yes I do have `'django.template.context_processors.request'` on my project/settings.py

Comment: @gglasses You've defined your `MEDIA_URL` to be `upload/`. Change it to `/upload/` and it should work (note the leading slash)

Comment: add a slash after the variable ie <img src="{{ request.get_host }}/{{ model.image.url }}" />

Comment: @marcusshep while adding a slash between the variables would work, it does seem (in my opinion) to be a little hacky. Adding the prepending slash to `MEDIA_URL` at least saves the boilerplate of a slash between variables each time you reference media.

Comment: You know what? your answer totally covers my question but it was indeed the stupidest question ever, I just realized that. I changed my `MEDIA_URL` to `/upload/` and relative urls now works for me. haha

Comment: Excellent! It happens to the best of us... I see a lot of confusion on SO regarding the serving of media and static files, so you're definitely not alone!

Comment: @curtis-olson I agree :) As soon as you commented the MEDIA_URL change I thought "oh well that's a much better solution"

Answer (score 0):

You can find top page url by `self.request._current_scheme_host`

For example, you can get it like this in class base view.

```
class SampleView(TemplateView):
   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
       context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
       context['host'] = self.request._current_scheme_host
       return context
```

In Template

```
{{ host }}{{ model.image.url }}
```

It's shows `https://example.com/sample.jpg`.

Answer (score 0):

Curtis's answer is very useful, but in more details it doesn't provide *http://* or *https://*

As an Complementary answer for Curtis's one, we can use:

```
<img src="http://{{ request.get_host }}{{ model.image.url }}" />
```

Or we can also use this method to get an absolute url:

```
<img src="{{ request.build_absolute_uri }}{{ model.image.url }}" />
```

---

This is very useful for example when we want create an Open Graph tag like this:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://{{ request.get_host }}{{ jumbotron.picture.url }}" />
```

or

```
<meta property="og:image" content="{{ request.build_absolute_uri }}{{ jumbotron.picture.url }}" />
```